# Dates on a graph in python?

Tags: python, date, graph

I have a very basic python understanding and need to code a graph with dates on the x-axis with values on the y-axis. I have looked through the answers given to others on here however none have worked on my programme (probably my error). I am using jupyter 4.2.3 to then open Python(conda root). Any help would be much appreciated

```
%matplotlib inline

from datetime import datetime

x = [datetime(year=1888, month=4, day=3),
 datetime(year=1888, month=8, day=7),
 datetime(year=1888, month=8, day=31)]

data = [x=x,y=[1, 2, 3]]

sym.plot(data)
```

Sorry, realise it's not a lot, just want to get it working before add anything proper.

Comment: You have a bit of a climb ahead of you before this is reasonably answered in a way that will be clear to you. Almost always, the code you find here needs to be adapted in some way to fit your program. Take a look at `matplotlib` e.g. http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html

Comment: Please give the code for something that you think came closest to your desired output and any error messages you got, or what went wtong. Without code, no answer can be better than a generic tutorial/answer that hasn't worked for you so far. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry new at this don't quite understand how it works yet. I've merged bits together and got this     %matplotlib inline

from datetime import datetime
x = [datetime(year=1888, month=4, day=3),
     datetime(year=1888, month=8, day=7),
     datetime(year=1888, month=8, day=31)]

data = [x=x,y=[1, 2, 3]]
sym.plot(data)  at the moment it's saying invalid santex but there has been quite a few other problems

Comment: You need to edit your original question to include that code with correct layout. It's illegible in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alterations from your posted code:

- `[x=x,y=[1, 2, 3]]` is not valid syntax here. The simplest explanation for plotting is just to think about `x` and `y` being separate lists for now. Don't try to put them together for now.
- `from datetime import datetime` I dislike this only because the `datetime` module is simply confusing enough with `datetime` appearing twice. Doing it the way you did will preclude you from using features such as `timedelta` which would make debugging a bit more difficult if you ever got stuck and asked another question.
- Using `pyplot` will give you code more in line with tutorials available online.

Your code might look something like the following instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

x = [dt.datetime(year=1888, month=4, day=3),
    dt.datetime(year=1888, month=8, day=7),
    dt.datetime(year=1888, month=8, day=31)]

y= [1, 2, 3] 

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @SarahRyall you're welcome. You might find it useful to search for "sentdex" on YouTube as he has plenty of tutorials on Python and a thorough playlist on matplotlib (I haven't watched that particular playlist but his others get you a pretty good grounding when you want to break into different aspects of programming in Python)